# The most appropriate way to format numbers in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, angularjs-filter

My problem is that I want to format numbers based on my language. For example, showing `123456.12345` in en-US as `123,456.12` or in fa-IR as `۱۲۳٬۴۵۶٫۱۲`.

The best solution I can imagine is writing an angular filter but I think it is very slow because I need to show too many numbers in the view.

**My question:** Is there any better way to handle this problem or I have to use angular filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1 with filters:**

You can include the relative locale script in index.html as stated [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n):

```
<html ng-app>
 <head>
….
   <script src="angular.js"></script>
   <script src="i18n/angular-locale_de-de.js"></script>
….
 </head>
</html>
```

Then using the built-in filter [`number`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number) you can format them easily

**Solution 2 with toLocaleString:**

If you don't want to use filter, you have to convert the numbers "manually" using [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) for each number you have:

```
$scope.myNumber = 9999.99;

$scope.myNumber.toLocaleString('de-DE');
```

This is a [JSFidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/j682oxqd/1) showing you how a number is formatted for de-DE locale instead the en-US one used by default

Comment: As I said in the question, filters are slow in angularjs. I am asking for a better solution.

Comment: I use JQuery Globalize which is a very nice library to handle these problems, but I have to do this conversion every time I need to show something in the view! I also looked for something related to html itself but found nothing!

Comment: I finally ended up changing the font and using filters (like your suggestions)